# Experiencing issues with VHDL Code ModelSim: Wave Generation

Tags: fpga, vhdl, frequency, physics, modelsim

I'm working on this project where I'm basically supposed to generate square wave (and other types of wave) using VHDL. The time period can be adjusted to either increase or decrease its frequency, and since this can be viewed on Intel's ModelSim, you can visually see the wave within the test bench you created.

I did manage to do this albeit not quite right, as I modified a state machine to work with a variable named "counter" to basically count at rising clock edges, creating a wave. I even created a concept chart of how the program would work:
[image]

As I wanted to generate a waveform of 100kHz on ModelSim, I used the clock frequency of the DE1-SoC board, being 50MHz. Its time period(for board clock) was extracted, being 20ns (0.00000002). For the frequency I wanted to generate, I just used the same T = 1/f and multiplied f(frequency) by 2 to account for both the lows and highs of the wave, resulting in the time period for 100kHz being 5 microseconds (0.000005). The variable N, was then calculated by dividing 5 microseconds by  20 nanoseconds to get 250. This was set as a general time period for "CLK" using ModelSim's Right Click Clock Period option. I also set a value of 250 for this counter variable, essentially following the system I drew.

Somehow I would end up with this:
[image]

Is there any reason on why it takes 6 billion pico seconds/60 milliseconds for the signal to change state? Did I miscalculate somewhere or am I just getting something wrong?

My code

```
-- Quartus Prime VHDL Template
-- Four-State Moore State Machine

-- A Moore machine's outputs are dependent only on the current state.
-- The output is written only when the state changes.  (State
-- transitions are synchronous.)

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity sqwave is

    port(
        clk      : in   std_logic;
        --nput   : in   std_logic;
        reset    : in   std_logic;
        output   : out  std_logic_vector(11 downto 0)
    );

end entity;

architecture rtl of sqwave is

    -- Build an enumerated type for the state machine
    type state_type is (lw, hg);

    -- Register to hold the current state
    signal state   : state_type;

begin

    -- Logic to advance to the next state
    process (clk, reset)
    variable counter : integer:=0; 
    begin
        if reset = '1' then
            state <= lw;
        elsif (rising_edge(clk)) then.
            case state is
                when lw=>
                    if counter <= 12 then
                        state <= lw;
                        counter:=counter+1;
                    else
                        state <= hg;
                        counter :=0;
                    end if;
                when hg=>
                    if counter <= 12 then
                        state <= hg;
                        counter:=counter+1;
                    else
                        state <= lw;
                        counter:=0;
                    end if;
            end case;
        end if;
    end process;

    -- Output depends solely on the current state
    process (state)
    begin
        case state is
            when lw =>
                output <= X"000";
            when hg =>
                output <= X"FFF";
        end case;
    end process;

end rtl;
```

Comment: Well, my VHDL is a bit rusty, but aren't you resetting `counter` each time the process runs, that is on _any clock cycle_? Wouldn't you need to store the value in a register?

Comment: Initialising counter to 0 ought to be in the reset clause.

Comment: Make sure every register is reset.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't enough information to tell you what is the root cause of the error you are seeing, but there are a few problems here that can be fixed, and a few pointers for how I would recommend do to things in general.

**Problem: Your test bench needs a valid RESET signal**

This is the biggest problem. Looking at your simulation waveforms, we see that the RESET signal has the value of `'U'` (uninitialized) during the entire simulation. So your state machine never goes through its reset. That's not what you wanted. Modify your test bench to make sure that RESET is asserted (`'1'`) for  a few clock cycles and then properly negated (`'0'`) during the rest of your simulation. *In a good simulation, no signal should ever have a `'U'` value after 0ns.*

**Problem: You should reset the value of `counter` in the reset clause**

In the comments user_1818839 is exactly right. Currently you are using an initialization value for the `counter` variable, i.e. `variable counter : integer:=0;`. It is super important to note that *this initialization value only applies during simulation, it has no effect on the final synthesized design*. That's the exact opposite of what any designer wants; ideally you would like the simulation to behave exactly like the code will behave in the target device. So I'd highly recommend getting rid of the initialization clause and adding `counter := 0;` to the reset clause instead.

**Advice: Take a look at the `counter` variable during simulation**

One of the cool things ModelSim allows you to do is monitor the value of variables in addition to signals. Look at the value of `counter` during the simulation and see if it's doing what you expect.

**Advice: take a closer look at the clock**

You show that your state transition doesn't happen until 62.5ms. This would correspond to 312000 clock cycles *if* your clock is running at 50MHz. Since things are not working as expected, we should presume nothing and verify everything. Zoom in on your waveform and make sure the clock is running at 50MHz as you expected.

**Suggestion: why not set the value of `output` inside the clocked process?**

This one is really a matter of personal taste, but nearly all modern FPGA devices have a register after each combinatorial logic block, so there isn't much advantage to having a purely combinatorial process like you do for setting the value of `output`. Either approach works, but I personally find code more readable if the value of `output` gets set inside the state machine. This one has absolutely nothing to do with the problem you're seeing, so I'd suggest you let this wait until after you've fixed that problem, or simply don't worry about it at all. (Like I said: "personal taste".)

Comment: Thanks for your response Mr Snub. At the time since I was not intending on using the RESET clause, I just kept its value uninitialized, but nevertheless thank you for informing me, I just drove an input of 1 and 0 in the simulation and everything worked as expected. Also for the movement of the counter variable, wouldn't that just "undeclare" counter and break the program? I'm just used to seeing define first use later in other languages, so I thought this same thing would occur here.

Comment: I also took a look at the counter variable, and after countless hours researching and grinding, I understood my mistakes and can now generate any frequency. However, the problem is that I keep seeing people say different things about setting the period for the CLK signal. Since, in my case, I was intending on using 50 MHz Clock frequency (meaning 20 ns) with intended Freq of 100kHz, some would state that this period would have to be halved to 10ns due to the state changes occurring within the same time period. I would either end up with 250 or 500, and just using 500 with a period of 10ns

Comment: (Continuation) would work as well as using 20ns with 250, meaning that for a CLK period of 20ns (or 10ns) I could use 250 or 500 respectively, setting both counters to either 250 or 500 to get the desired time period and frequency for a 100kHz wave. I do apologise if this explanation sounds confusing, but I just do not understand why different methods are used to reach the same answer, unless I (most likely) am understanding something wrong about this process.

Comment: I wasn't saying to "move" the counter variable. You should be able to monitor it in ModelSim, without any modification to your code. I've forget exactly how to do this, but I recall doing it in the past so I know it's possible.

Comment: ...and yes your explanation about CLK frequency and dividers is confusing the heck out of me; I don't know what you are trying to say. Getting more careful about the wording might clear up the problem itself. The clock *period* is always the time from one rising edge to the next. Since your process only responds to the rising edge of CLK, your output needs to complete its full up-and-down cycle in 500 CLK cycles. (The high portion of your output should be 250 CLK cycles wide, and the low portion of that should be too.)

Comment: Ah because what confused me about prior explanations from other sources were the "because double state changes occur in clock cycle as counter variable switches from low to high and vice versa, clock period needs to be halved" explanation. But with yours, everything is kept the same and 500 is just used instead, with 20ns as the clock time period. This makes sense, its just the other sources saying different things that boggle my mind and at the time I was not sure who was correct